# Phase margin plot of LDO

Tags: cmos, ldo, phase, bode-plot

For this LDO circuit design at https://github.com/promach/LDO/tree/development ,

1) which exact circuit node(s) contributes to the zeroes near 1MHz after removing CL ?

2) If I remove "AC 1" from Vref, why the whole bode plot becomes erratic ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it ok to have two active ac sources in this simulation? Also, I can see this is an open-loop configuration with the \$LC\$ but do you confirm the operating bias point is ok, I mean the output is at the expected value for this analysis?

Comment: @VerbalKint operating point bias check is inside DC, the above are for AC